# How to find FTP Host and username and password in docker

Tags: linux, docker

I'm running two webs on docker both using joomla one with 127.0.0.1:8383 and another one with 127.0.0.1:8181. in the web that has the address 127.0.0.1:8383 should connect to the other one so I need to know the Host the username and the password of ftp for 127.0.0.1:8181. I didn't find any command that I can use it on docker server that is linux to find this information (FTP HOST; FTP USERNAME; FTP PASSWORD).

docker network ls return

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
f37b31437406        bridge              bridge              local
6677ac044ead        host                host                local
57d840968a45        none                null                local
461f00275394        site_default        bridge              local
3ea97a6df8a8        sitea1_default      bridge              local
```

127.0.0.1:8181 docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'  

services:
      web:
        build:
          context: ./
          dockerfile: docker/web/Dockerfile
        restart: always
        ports:
         - "8181:80"
        volumes:
          - .:/alpha
      phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        depends_on:
          - mysql
        ports:
          - "8282:80"
        environment:
          PMA_HOST: mysql
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: alpha
      mysql:
        build:
          context: ./
          dockerfile: docker/database/Dockerfile
        restart: always
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: alpha
          MYSQL_DATABASE: alpha
          MYSQL_USER: alpha
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: alpha
        volumes:
          - my-db:/var/lib/mysql
    volumes:
      my-db:
```

127.0.0.1:8383 docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  joomla:
    image: joomla
    restart: always
    links:
      - joomladb:mysql
    ports:
      - 8383:80
    volumes:
      - "./:/var/www/html"
    environment:
      JOOMLA_DB_HOST: joomladb
      JOOMLA_DB_PASSWORD: alpha

  joomladb:
    image: mysql:5.6
    ports:
      - 3306
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "./data:/var/lib/mysql"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: alpha
      MYSQL_DATABASE: alpha
      MYSQL_USER: alpha
```

I already installed ftp on server

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vsftpd
```

Comment: you can link the web with FTP container, and you can pass the FTP user name and password in ENV. also would be better to share docker-compose

Comment: @Adiii I add the docker-compose.yml

Comment: where is FTP server is running? it in the host machine or some where i do not see in the compose?

Comment: @Adiii the ftp is installed on the server using : `sudo apt-get update` et 
`sudo apt-get install vsftpd`

Comment: okay adding as an asnwer and hope will help.

Comment: @Adiii I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear and it does not exist any FTP command in docker. 
A best practice is to create a new FTP container and linking it to your web app container.

Comment: my knowledge on docker is minimum how to link ftp container to my web